# How to set up floating action button expansion direction in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I try to give to a height of floating action button a set of constraints, that will look like "bottom of button is 8dp from bottom of screen, top of button is 92% of screen size from top of screen, but, if button height (according to previous constraints) become lower than 40dp, expand button in **top** direction to achieve this height". I've almost done this successfully, but, when  button starts to expand to achieve 40dp height, it expands in both directions - top and bottom - and I can't restrict it expansion to only top direction. Are there any ways to do what I want to do? Also, I have more global question - are there any ways to give to one constraint higher priority, than to another?

Code of button:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/amtheme"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline23"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline9"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_min="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline13" />
```

Screenshot 1: Button is 8dp from bottom of screen, 92% from top of screen, everything is fine!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFX0e.png

Screenshot 2: I change screen orientation, so button becomes too small, it adjusts to minimal height constraint - and expands in both directions instead of expanding in top direction, moving offscreen.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaTYp.png

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here any specific reasons why you are constraining it like this.

Comment: I want to make size of my button proportional to height of screen if it's height is large enough. However, when screen change orientation, for example, button becomes too small, so I want to give it constant size in this case. I found way to do it recently, however, I am developing my first android app now, and may be these constraints aren't best code practice. May be there are better ways to achieve these goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer myself. Adding `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8"` in code helped me, may be it will help someone else!

Comment: You can also use different layouts or even constrained_height